# Compare multiple unique strings in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Edit: I am using Python 2.7

I have a given 'matrix' as shown below which contains multiple lists of strings.  I want to sort through matrix and only print out the row(s) which only contain a specific set of strings.

Can any one give me a hint on how to go about this?

What I have tried so far:

```
matrix = [("One", "Two", "Three"),
("Four", "Five", "Six"),
("Seven", "Eight", "One"),
("Four", "Five", "Six"),
("One", "Three", "Six")]

for index, data in enumerate(matrix):
    if "One" and "Three" and "Six" in data:
        print data
```

desired output:

```
("One", "Three", "Six")
```

actual output(as of now):

```
('Four', 'Five', 'Six')
('Four', 'Five', 'Six')
('One', 'Three', 'Six')
```

Answer (score 8):

Your test is incorrect, you want to test each string separately with `in`:

```
if "One" in data and "Three" in data and "Six" in data:
```

`and` does not group operands for the `in` test; each component is evaluated separately:

```
("One") and ("Three") and ("Six" in data):
```

which leads to the result of `"Six" in data` being returned; the other two values are certainly always True as they are non-empty strings.

The better approach is to use a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
if {"One", "Three", "Six"}.issubset(data):
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use sets for this:

```
matrix = [("One", "Two", "Three"),
("Four", "Five", "Six"),
("Seven", "Eight", "One"),
("Four", "Five", "Six"),
("One", "Three", "Six")]

target = {"One", "Three", "Six"}

for row in matrix:
    if target <= set(row):
         print row
```

Here, `target <= set(row)` checks whether `target` is a subset of `set(row)`.

The reason your code doesn't work is that the following:

```
if "One" and "Three" and "Six" in data:
```

is equivalent to:

```
if bool("One") and bool("Three") and ("Six" in data):
```

Since `bool("One")` and `bool("Three")` are `True`, the entire expression simply checks whether `"Six"` is in `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that you're misusing the `and`

try

```
"One" and "Three"
```

in interactive console - it would output `True`, because "One" and "Three" are 'cast' tobooleans, and they're  treated as true values. So, for this to work you should rewrite the condition to

```
if "One" in data and "Three" in data and "Six" in data
```

Comment: `'One' and 'Three'` actually returns `'Three'`, because `'One'` evaluates (it’s not cast to boolean) to True, so the return value is the second operand to `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test it as a set:

```
for data in matrix:
    if set(["Three","Six","One"]).issubset(set(data)):
        print data
```

results in:

```
('One', 'Three', 'Six').
```

Notice that as you test as a set there is problem with the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with your `if` statement

```
 if "One" and "Three" and "Six" in data:
```

you gets all list that contains `Six`,(*notice  your output*)

`("Seven", "Eight", "One")` and `("One", "Two", "Three")` not printed because `Six` is not in you tuples:

Additionally, Every string (not `""`) if is true in python for example:

```
>>> if("One"):
...     print "Yes"
... else:
...     print "No"
... 
Yes
```

So you if expression

```
 if "One" and "Three" and "Six" in data:
```

is equivalent to

```
 if True and True and "Six" in data:
```

that is equivalent to:

```
 if "Six" in data:
```

Where as you need where "One", "Three", and "Six" all are present so do like:

```
if  ( ("One" in data) and 
      ("Three" in data) and 
      ("Six" in data)
     ):
```

As @Martijn Pieters answered. In addition get one more technique:

```
>>> target = {"One", "Three", "Six"}
>>> for data in matrix:
...     if (set(map(tuple, data)) <= set(map(tuple, target))):
...             print data
... 
('One', 'Three', 'Six')
>>>
```